# Where to find the most recent mapping between Clinical and Waveform Records?

Tags: mimic-iii

I saw a few mappings between Clinical and Waveform Records:

- http://www.physionet.org/physiobank/tutorials/using-mimic2/#linking (MIMIC Waveform database 2V2)
- http://physionet.org/physiobank/database/mimic2wdb/MAP-CW (MIMIC Waveform database 2V3)
- http://physionet.org/physiobank/database/mimic2wdb/matched/ (MIMIC Waveform database 2V3 +  MIMIC II Clinical Database version 2.6 (or later))

Is the last one in this list the most recent mapping between Clinical and Waveform Records?

http://physionet.org/physiobank/database/mimic2wdb/MAP-CW looks incomplete. It has no patient whose ID is greater than 26715 while http://physionet.org/physiobank/database/mimic2wdb/matched/ has up to 32805.

Answer (score 1):

https://mimic.physionet.org/mimicdata/waveforms/ :

> Work to link waveform data with the MIMIC-III Clinical Database is still underway. Please check here for updates on our progress.