# Mapping between mimic-iii clinical data and mimic II V3 waveforms

Tags: mimic-iii

How can I map between a subject id and and its waveform record id in the mimic II v3 DB?

For example, what is the waveform record id of a patient with subject_id = 8915?

In the previous MIMIC II Waveform DB I found that this patient mapped to case_id = a44193

Comment: Related: [Where to find the most recent mapping between Clinical and Waveform Records?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/6401/1652)